# how to filter numbers that end with .0 or .5?

Tags: r, regex, tidyr, stringr, grepl

I am trying to filter out all the data that contains fares that do not end with  $.0, $.00, $.50 or $.5

The fare column should always end with `$.0, $.00, $.50, $.5`

Here's how my data looks like:

```
df = 
 |date      |id   |fare
1|2018-11-25|12345|5.50
2|2018-11-26|12345|2.0
3|2018-11-26|12355|2.61
4|2018-11-27|12345|12.60
5|2018-11-27|12348|22.65
```

I tried using the grepl function but it only kind of solved my problem. It contained what i wanted but was missing a lot of data that I expected to be there.

```
df[grepl("\\.(?:.00$|.0$|.50$|.5$)$",df$fare), ]
```

I want to create a new df that contains rows 3:5

```
dfgood = 
 |date      |id   |fare
3|2018-11-26|12355|2.61
4|2018-11-27|12345|12.60
5|2018-11-27|12348|22.65
```

Comment: Small tip: things might be simpler if you multiplied them all by 100 first.

Comment: rows 3:5 should be in the final output because?

Comment: You could try `df[df$fare %% .5 > 0, ]`.

Comment: Really depends if your data is numeric or character. If character, stick with `grepl` methods. If numeric, mutliply and `%%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using base r

```
##create some basic data
df = data.frame(date = c(1,2,3,4,5),
        id = c(12345,12345,12355,12345,12348),
        fare = c(5.5,2,2.61,12.60,22.65))


df[which(!(df$fare %% 1) %in% c(0.5,0)),]
```

Comment: I like how you say base r and the first thing you do is call tibble

Comment: Haha but really nice solution

Comment: Great. Would you mind confirming the answer and upvoting?

Comment: Unfortunately can't upvote yet but i gave you the check!

Answer (score 1):

This `regex` should do it

```
# If stored as character
df[!grepl('\\.5$|\\.0$|\\.00$|\\.50$', df$fare, perl = TRUE),]
# Else
df[!grepl('\\.5$|\\.0$|\\.00$|\\.50$', format(round(df$fare, 2), nsmall = 1), perl = TRUE),]
```

Comment: This worked! I appreciate that you were able to modify my code :)

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
library(dplyr)
dfgood <- df %>% filter((100*fare)%%50!=0)
```